# Python newbie array - list conversion

Tags: python

I have an array like this type `["1" "2" "3"]`, how can I change this into a list `[1, 2, 3]` Could some one please help me regarding this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
myList = [ "1", "2", "3" ]
myList = [ int(i) for i in myList ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `["1", "2", "3"]` and `[1, 2, 3]` are lists. The former is just a list of strings, whereas the latter is a list of integers. Call [`int`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) on every element to convert it to an integer, like this:

```
str_list = ["1", "2", "3"]
int_list = [int(e) for e in str_list]
# or ...
int_list = map(int, str_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is really ["1" "2" "3"], it will be concatenated into a single string like such ["123"] so you'll need split the string like so:

```
newList = []
for n in xrange(len(oldList[0])):
    newList.append(int(oldList[0][n]))
```